# Why this attributeError comes all the time,how i fix this

Tags: python, sockets

when i running my chat program,an attribute error is there all the time.
could someone please explain why this error occur in my code and suggest solutions.
the chat program is

```
import socket
import select
import sys
#list for socket descriptors
socket_list = []
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 5009
def chat_server():
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INIT, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind((host, port))
    server_socket.listen(10)

    # add server socket to the list
    socket_list.append(server_socket)

    print "chat server started on port" + str(port)

    while 1:
        #get the list of sockets to be read through select
        read, write, error = select.select(socket_list, [], [])
        for sock in read:
            if sock == server_socket:
                sock_obj, addr = server_socket.accept()
                socket_list.append(sock_obj)
                print "Client (%s, %s) connected"%addr)
                broadcast(srver_socket, sock_obj,
                      "[%s, %s] entered our chat address" %addr)
            else :
                #process data recieved from client,
                data = sock.recv(4000)
                if data :
                    broadcast(server_socket0, sock,
                          'Message[' + addr[0] + ':'
                           + str(addr[1]) + '] -' + data.strip())
                else :
                    # remove the broken socket
                    if sock in socket_list :
                        socket_list.remove(sock)
                    broadcast(server_socket, sock,
                          "Client (%s, %s) is offline" %addr)

    server_socket.close()

# broadcast the messages to our clients
def broadcast (server_socket, sock, msg):
    for sockets in socket_list :
        if sockets != server_socket and sockets != sock :
            socket.send(msg)
```

when i run this code the following errors occur,
please give some suggestion to make it correct

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chat_server.py", line 55, in <module>
    chat_server()
  File "chat_server.py", line 11, in chat_server
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INIT, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AF_INIT'
```

Comment: You mean `socket.AF_INET` do you? (not `AF_INIT`).

Answer (score 1):

Which version you are using, did not find socket.AF_INIT

socket.AF_INET exist in python 2.7 version (https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html)

Comment: Sorry for that guys, its a typing error, i just i didnt notice it